# Windows batch files: how to compare command line argument to an integer

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, integer, command-line-arguments

I am only very new to batch file programming and I have tried to find the solution online, but failed.
My batch file calls a c program passing it's own command line arguments to the program then does subsequent steps which depend on the value of the fourth argument (which is an integer).
I would like to do an extra step in my batch file if %4 is equal to 3. I have placed some echo test statements. But only the "testno" gets printed even if I enter 3 as my fourth argument.

---

Batch file name: p2debug1234.bat

---

Batch file code:

---

```
@echo off
@setlocal 
p2task1 %1 %2 %3 %4
start mi_viewer %1
start mi_viewer %2
echo %4
echo 3
If ("%4"== "3") (echo testyes) Else (echo testno)
echo testif
```

---

Command prompt snapshot:

---

```
H:\ELEC4622\labs\data>p2debug1234 pens_rgb.bmp test.bmp 2 3

3
3
testno
testif
```

---

Please help me make a valid comparison.

Best Regards,
Julia

Comment: Are you really using ms-dos? Or are you possibly using windows? If so, then this has nothing to do with ms-dos (which is a name of a a operating system not the command prompt).

Comment: I am using windows, you are right. Sorry.

Comment: I just always thought that windows was just software that extended MS-DOS. I'm pretty sure that was what it was to begin with (from memory). But I guess that is no longer the case with the later versions of windows.

Comment: It was, back when you had windows 3.11. But after windows 95 the shell has been part of windows not the other way around. So you would have been right 18 years ago.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change line:

```
If ("%4"== "3") (echo testyes) Else (echo testno)
```

to:

```
If "%4"=="3" (echo testyes) Else (echo testno)
```

Comment: You should vote up and or accept answers. That's the way to thank in stack overflow. Not doing any of these things break the idea of stack overflow.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I have never posted to this place before